# progressbar.js error TypeError: $(...).metisMenu is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, browserify, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to get progressbar.js up and running but I am getting this error in my console `TypeError: $(...).metisMenu is not a function`
I switched from bower to browesrify and I was using metisMenu at one point however I have deleted metisMenu folder and removed it from package.json

Why is browserify **bundling** metisMenu into my Browserify file findem.js?

```
var ProgressBar = require('progressbar');

var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#progress', {
    color: 'red',
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'easeInOut'
});
circle.animate(1);
```

Browserify command

```
browserify js/main.js -o js/findem.js -d
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "thewhiteFox",
  "title": "thewhiteFox",
  "version": "0.1.4",
  "homepage": "http://thewhitefox.ninja/",
  "author": "theWhiteFox",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.10",
    "gulp-header": "^1.8.7",
    "gulp-image-optimization": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "progressbar": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `Why is browserify bundling metisMenu into my Browserify file findem.js?` - clearly it isn't doing that, because **$(...).metisMenu is not a function**  - obviously some of your code (or some other library you use) somewhere is calling `$(...).metisMenu`

Comment: In my browserify file findem.js ```$(function() {
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
});```

Comment: yeah, that's the output ... you need to search the inputs (and any "config" files browerify may use) to see how that's getting in there

Comment: Is it something to do with switching from bower to browserify, do I need to update the package.json file?

Comment: well, what do you see in package.json (we can't see it, remember)

Comment: Yes good point I will update my question with the package.json file.

Comment: does browserify use any other "config" files?

Comment: Nope, not that I know of.. I fixed the error.. Thanks

Comment: @StephenÓConnor how ? share code